# Create an outlook calendar add-in

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an outlook add-in following the official Microsoft Documentation: [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator)

I am using a MacBook Pro M1, so I am following the tutorial using Yeoman generation.

Everything is working fine. I can see the add-in when in the emails, but  I would like to see the add-in also in the calendar or while creating a meeting.

Following this tutorial I see the add-in only in the emails.

Mail Screenshot:[image: Mail Screenshot]

Calendar Screenshot:
[image: calendar Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you specified correct rules in the manifest file:

```
 <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
```

Plus in the manifest file for the ribbon UI you need to specify different extension points for messages and appointments.

You can find the full sample add-in source code at
https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo .